# How to remove space before <br>

Tags: html, css

I have a footer which contains two informations about address and phones like this

[image]

For the address (the top section) I am using `<p>` and `<br/>` inside of it and the phones section (the bottom section) I am using `<span>` with `display: block;` attribute and this is my HTML

```
<div class="information">
            <div class="informationAddresses">
                <p>
                    TANOBEL FOOD
                    <br>
                    PT. Sariguna Primatirta
                    <br>
                    Jl. A. Yani 41-43
                    <br>
                    Gedangan, Sidoarjo
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="informationContact">
                <span>Call Center <a href="tel:+628001112536">0800 111 2536</a></span>
                <span>Hotline <a href="tel:+623170109110">(031) 701 09 110</a></span>
                <span>SMS <a href="tel:+6277850800033">+6277 85080 0033</a></span>
                <span><a href="mailto:customer@tanobelfood.com">customer@tanobelfood.com</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have a problem with `<br/>` inside of `<p>` tag which have space before return to next line. Can I remove this with CSS or should I use another tag?

Thank you, and sorry for my English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<div style="white-space:pre-line">
```

Comment: Aw.. thanks it works like charm.. thank you..